# dotnet custom template discoverability in private NuGet Feed

Tags: .net-core, nuget, artifactory

I have created a dotnet custom template with a nuget package following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates.

My csproj file that builds the nuget package is exactly the one in the link above.

After pushing to our private NuGet feed (JFrog Artifactory) I can install the template with `dotnet new -i MyTemplate --nuget-source MyNuGetFeed`, but can not update it with the `dotnet new --update-apply` command and the template does not show up in the `dotnet new MyTemplate --search` or the `dotnet new --update-check` commands, I've tried appending the `--nuget-source` flag, but that does not seem to work either.

Is there something I need to do for these commands to work with a private feed?